# GitVersion: How to rollback SemVer numbers changes by Commit Messages?

Tags: git, semantic-versioning, gitversion

Hello I am testing GitVersion and I added a Commit Message **+semver:minor** and now the minor number of the version is increased. If I do it by mistake and what to **rollback** what is recommended?

-> I tried with a Revert and it didn't work because the version is based on the commit messages, but I am wondering if we have lot of commits after the Commit Message with the SemVer increase and later we want to fix it. Maybe changing the base GitVersion.yml is the easiest way.

-> I achieve what I want using Cherry-Pick, selecting the commits and placing in another branch, then deleting the branch with the wrong commit messages. I am looking for something that could be easier than that.

Comment: I know nothing of `GitVersion`, but in general you want to revert a commit using `git revert`, which tells Git to play a _new_ commit on top of your branch which is a sort of mirror image of the commit which you want to undo.  `git revert` also works with a range of commits.

Comment: Yeap, basically I notice later that a revert will not result in a "version revert" because the version in git version, in my case, is calculated by the Commit Messages (+semver:minor for example)... I updated my post to show how I achieve the version revert, but seems a bit clumsy for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the GitVersion configuration file, you can add a list of the commits (i.e. the SHA's) that you want GitVersion to ignore as part of establishing the correct semantic version number.

This takes the following format:

```
ignore:
  sha:
    - 2a4757b270f7946122ba6622e3d2e72b2b2808a7
    - 3e91c23637b97bc4e4c3234f93ffd03e6af70e8c
```

You can see a full example of this in use [here](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/blob/develop/GitVersion.yml)

Comment: That's a nice one! Very useful, in the case of some wrong commit.